# Storm data structures - map vs separated values?

Tags: apache-storm

I'm using **Storm** to parse and save data from **Kafka**. The data comes in as some identifiers and then a **map<string,string>** of varying size. After some munging the end goal is Cassandra.

Should I send the data as one block of tuples or split up the map and send each piece separately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A tuple should represent a "unit of work" for the next bolt in the stream.  If you think of your map as a single entity that gets processed as a single, albeit complex, object then the map should be emitted as a single tuple.  If you want different bolts independently processing different map attributes, then break the map into subsequently processable subsets of attributes and emit multiple tuples.

Comment: Does this apply if I need to break up the map to write to two tables? One for everything and one for a smaller row cache?

Comment: If the map can be efficiently used as input for both inserts then you probably don't need to break the map up.  Only if you see some glaring inefficiency in moving an entire map to a bolt that only does the smaller insert should you deal with smaller tuples.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the size of the tuple you want to send.

Every tuple you emit in Storm will be taken as a serialized message to transmit from one executor to another. You should also take the performance of Netty and LMAX into consideration, since they are used in the latest version of Storm for Inter-worker communication and Intra-worker communication. That is, settings like

> - Config.TOPOLOGY_RECEIVER_BUFFER_SIZE
> - Config.TOPOLOGY_TRANSFER_BUFFER_SIZE
> - Config.TOPOLOGY_EXECUTOR_RECEIVE_BUFFER_SIZE
> - Config.TOPOLOGY_EXECUTOR_SEND_BUFFER_SIZE

should be taken into account. You could take a look at [Understanding the Internal Message Buffers of Storm](http://www.michael-noll.com/blog/2013/06/21/understanding-storm-internal-message-buffers/) for more details.